# Sequence name as a task input

Tags: uvm

I have a SPB register sequence which sets up the hardware register values in a particular configuration.  The values of this configuration are used by a subsequent DAI sequence, by assigning the register values to the DAI sequence values.  I have managed this correctly using the following code to assign the register values to temporary ints to be used to constraint the DAI Sequence:

```
 task assign_reg_value();

    `uvm_info ("VIRT_SEQ_MODEL_PRINT", $sformatf ("Initial Register Setup : %s", ljf_reg_wr_seq.model.sprint()), UVM_LOW)



    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Get the register field value and assign it to the temporary variable. These are used for the serial 
    //sequence
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //DAI_CTRL
    seq_ser_format      = ljf_reg_wr_seq.model.DAI_CTRL.format.get();

    //MORE LINES SIMILAR TO ABOVE HERE 

endtask
```

However, in the event of running more than one register sequence to have different configurations in a single simulation, I require a method of generalising the above task such that it takes the sequence name argument.  Without this, I would need to replicate the ~50 lines of code and change the sequence name.  The pseudo code below shows the functionality that I require:

```
seq_ser_format = <seq_name>.model.DAI_CTRL.format.get();
```

I guess that there is a way to do this by setting the register sequence name in the configuration database before it is run, then retrieving it inside the task after it has finished running.  Does anybody have any suggestions for this implementation? Can it be done using the config database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test/virtual sequence, you can implement your task as follows:

```
task assign_reg_value(my_base_sequence seq);
  // ...
  seq_ser_format = seq.get_format_reg();
endtask
```

I assume your sequences are extended from base class `my_base_sequence`. Then you need to implement the above function `get_format_reg()` in your `my_base_sequence` as `virtual` method and override it in your subclasses.

```
class my_base_sequence extends uvm_sequence;
  // ...
  virtual function int get_format_reg();
     // leave it empty
     $display("Not implemented in base class");
  endfunction
endclass

class ljf_reg_wr_sequence extends my_base_sequence;
// ...
  virtual function int get_format_reg();
    return this.mode1.DAI_CTRL.format.get();
  endfunction
endclass
```

Then in your test/virtual sequence:

```
// ...
ljf_reg_wr_sequence ljf_reg_wr_seq;
other_reg_sequence other_seq;
// ... create sequence

assign_reg_value(ljf_reg_wr_seq);
// do something
assign_reg_value(other_seq);
// ...
```

Comment: I have approximately 15 register fields to 'get()'.  This method will become completeley unmanageable as it will require a seperate function for each in the base class and in every subclass, no?

Comment: I see. In this case, just implement 15 separate functions in the base class once for all. Then you'll have one generic `assign_reg_value` function.

Comment: Or you don't even need 15 functions provided that the register handle is implemented in the base class. Just make sure that the reg is not `null` when you call `assign_reg_value(your_seq);`

Comment: The reg model handle is implemented in the sequence base class.  What would the function look like?  Would I just have 15 lines similar lines for each register field?

Comment: Yes, only 15 lines regardless how many different sequences you have.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for your assistance, accepted this as a solution.